# Track javascript runtime errors

Tags: javascript, error-handling

Is there any way to capture all type of console errors?
Actually, I want to store all console errors to the database so I can fix serious issues of my PHP website.

Here is my current code to catch errors but this code is not capturing internal server errors and some other kind of errors like

> www-widgetapi.js:99 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow':
>   The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match
>   the recipient window's origin

Current script that I have

```
function ErrorSetting(msg, file_loc, line_no) {
    var e_msg=msg;
    var e_file=file_loc;
    var e_line=line_no;
    var   error_d = "Error in file: " + file_loc +
                        "\nline number:" + line_no +
                         "\nMessage:" + msg;
    if(logJsErrors){
        theData = "file="+file_loc+"&line="+line_no+"&err="+msg;

        ajaxCtrl(
            function(){
                return true;
            },Helpers.RootURL()+"/logs/index",theData
        );
    }

    if(isDebugging){
        console.error(error_d);
    }

    return true;
}
window.onerror = ErrorSetting;
```

I really appreciate your efforts.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could perform a kind of prototype of `console.log`, when you call `console.log` an ajax is fired, so you could do somethig like this:

```
(function () {
        var postCons = console.log;
        console.log = function (err) {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            postCons.apply(this, arguments);
            xhttp.open("POST", "log.php", true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {//you could avoid this step
                    alert(this.responseText);//response from php
                }
            };
            xhttp.send("data="+encodeURI(err));
        }
    })()
```

In `log.php` you could do whatever you want with `$_POST['data']` , you could use something like `urldecode($_POST['data'])` .

Comment: Hi Emeeus, Thanks for the reply. I am already doing that in ajaxCtrl() function.

Comment: so, I don't understand, because if you place this function at the top of the scope, you store all console logs. But if you want to store all php errors you should use some error handler like this http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php